# Having trouble referring to a method in another class

Tags: java, methods

I'm almost completely new to Java and programming in general (my main degree is in Law but I'm hoping to open myself up to programming as I truly believe it's going to be an essential skill in a couple years).

I've created two classes, `LabClass` and `Student`, and the point is to enroll students into the class, while giving them credits for enrolling.

Here's the method in my `Student` class that I'm trying to access:

```
public void addCredits(int additionalPoints)
{
    credits += additionalPoints;
}
```

And here's the method in my `LabClass` class that I'm trying to use:

```
public void enrollStudent(Student newStudent)
{
    if(students.size() == capacity) {
        System.out.println("The class is full, you cannot enrol.");
    }
    else {
        students.add(newStudent);
    }
    students.addCredits(50);
}
```

What I don't understand is why BlueJ says that it cannot find the method "addCredits". I'm a real beginner so I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Props for submitting a well-written question that includes all of the relevant code and a good explanation of what you've done and tried.

Comment: For future readers, it would be helpful to edit this question to show where in `LabClass` the variable `students` is declared and what type it is. This really is a very good question, and I see you have received some good answers already.

Comment: For the future, consider this: a method is being called to enroll the student into a class, which occasionally can't succeed (i.e. if class is full). When that happens, you print things in `System.out`, but your program overall has no way of knowing whether student was enrolled successfully. You should either return some value that would represent success or failure (simplest is `boolean`, but possibilities are endless), or throw an exception if enrollment is not possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never show what the variable `students` is. However it seems to be an array of `Student`s. You're invoking `addCredits` on an array of `Students`, instead of on the variable `newStudent`, which is what I suppose you want to do. The correct way of doing this would be:

```
public void enrollStudent(Student newStudent)
{
    if(students.size() == capacity) {
        System.out.println("The class is full, you cannot enrol.");
    }
    else {
        newStudent.addCredits(50);
        students.add(newStudent);
    }

}
```

Comment: @Brian If this is best answer, it would be helpful to mark the checkbox showing this as your accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

Students is an ArrayList or something... not a student. I think maybe you mean to say `newStudent.addCredits(50);`

Comment: You are a legend THANK YOU. +1.